# Does Ruby have Skip(n) like C#?

Tags: c#, ruby, list

In C# you can do:

```
var list = new List<int>(){1,2,3,4,5};
list.skip(2).take(2); // returns (3,4)
```

I'm trying to learn all the Ruby enumerable methods, but I don't see an equivalent for skip(n)

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
a.skip(2).take(2) # take exists, skip doesn't
```

So, what's the "best" Ruby way to do it?

all of these work, but they're pretty ugly.

```
a.last(a.length - 2).take(2)
(a - a.first(2)).take(2)
a[2...a.length].take(2)
```

Comment: oh, there it is, thanks much mike

Comment: What is wrong with `list[2, 2]` ?

Comment: @oldergod oh, that is awesome! what's the name of that so i can google it?

Comment: nice, thats sugar for `slice`. i love it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `drop`. From the [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-drop):

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0]
a.drop(3)             #=> [4, 5, 0]
```